# Understanding how the bayesian filtering works in SciKit and improving accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm building a simple spam filter using SciKit, and I'm a bit unsure with my results. I have a dataset that has around 5000 rows of data, the last column of which is a boolean value that specifies if the email was spam or ham, and the other columns specify data such as the average length of uninterrupted sequences of capital letters.

In my code I have the following:

```
X = dataset[:,:57] # the first 57 col, excluding the answer col
Y = dataset[:,-1]  # the final row with the boolean spam/ham value
xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(X, Y)
bNB = BernoulliNB(binarize = True)
bNB.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
yPred = bNB.predict(xTest)
score =  accuracy_score(yExpect, yPred)
print("result: ", score)
```

And I cut the columns so that X is the first 57 columns, and Y is the last column with the spam/ham value.

Then I run `train_test_split` on this X, Y, to produce an xTrain xTest, and a yTrain, yTest value.

My accuracy for this is quite low, how can I improve the accuracy? I've made two observations:

If I reduce the `test_sample` size (teast_train_split defaults at 0.25 so 25% of the data set) to say 0.01, the accuracy increases to 99% or even 100%.

The accuracy increases to 99% or 100% when I include the final row containing the spam/ham boolean value. Though I feel like this is not how you are supposed to do it, and the point is not using the result in the training data?

My question here is why. Can someone explain to me why these two observations I've made happen? And whether they are 'correct' or not, i.e. if it's cheating to include boolean result in the data set, or if it's cheating to have a very small test size?

Comment: Hey @flooblebit, don't forget to [upvote my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes including the boolean result is "cheating".

Basically what you are doing is you are trying to build a model that should predict a variable from a set of variables in which it belongs. The model will very easily pick up on the fact that they are the same.
More problematic, if you place yourself in the case of a new email coming, you don't have that boolean result to try and predict whether it's a spam, your model is rendered useless.

On your other point, yes it's not relevant to diminish the test set size. It is less statistically relevant. You could however do [leave one out cross validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html) and see if it's actually a matter of your model needing more data but I doubt it.